# How to suppress output from tee based on variable in Bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tee

So, in the following example:

```
echo "text to write to file but also not send to stdout" | tee -a $logfile 1> /dev/null
```

The output does not get printed on the terminal. But when I try doing the same action based on a variable it does not work.

Ex:

```
$loud=""
if [ -z $loud ]; then
  route_devnull="1> /dev/null"
else
  route_devnull=""
fi
echo "text to write to file but also not send to stdout" | tee -a $logfile $route_devnull
```

How can I get the second example to work? Or should I try another way to suppress the messages?

Comment: You should explain why you are trying to do this.

Comment: Well, the code kind of gives it away but it's meant to suppress the printing of messages that also get written into a log file. Basically to allow printing of extra debug info on the terminal rather than reading it from a log file later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: `echo "text to write to file but also not send to stdout" | eval tee -a $logfile $route_devnull`

`bash` does not evaluate variables as commands. You can write

```
echo "abc && touch new"
```

and it will print `abc && touch new` to the terminal. This is by design, since strings can be input from users, and we don't want to trust their commands, since they can do malicious things like trying to break our computer.

This is where [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash) comes in.

Instead of first executing the command, eval reads and *evaluates* all the arguments to construct another command and then execute it. Example:

```
eval echo "abc && touch new"
```

Just shove `eval` before whatever you want evaluated before execution. And by "just shove" I mean "think very carefully about using `eval`"